# BootStrap - Background color extend beyond with of container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am starting out with bootstrap here and I want my page to limit itself to 1170px which is the container class standard, but I want the color to continue across the full width of the page.

The only idea I can think of is:

```
<div class="container-fluid BGtoExtendWholePage headerBG">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
         Main Body of Page - Header
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid BGtoExtendWholePage ContentBG">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
         Main Body of Page - Main Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just create another wrapper and give it a bg color?

Answer (score 0):

There's big arguments against nesting containers in Bootstrap (cue the person to post a link to the bit of documentation saying not to) but I found this to work.

You nest a container within a container-fluid - note the use of p-0 to remove the padding from the inner container.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-red mb-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container p-0 mt-6 mb-6">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a `full-width` background color that is the same in your whole project then you could simply add a `<body>` tag at the beginning and end of your code (if it isn't already there) and add the following to your CSS

```
body {
 background-color: color-choise;
}
```

Fill in the `color-choise` with the color you want it to be.

Comment: No that is not what I want. That would be easy.

Comment: Can't edit my comment. Thats not what I am looking for. That would be easy as you did. My designer wants that each section 's background continues across the width. That's why I showed 2 sections. Is have to make another one for each section of the page

Comment: @Yoni then instead of using the `<div class="container-fluid">` use a `<div class="row">` and give each row like you did with the `container-fluid` classes an extra class in wich you define the background. Sadly i think this is the easiest solution since each background section differs from the others.